# Term for creating Terminology

Tags: terminology, academia, academic-writing

I’ve been struggling to remember a word for “creating discrete terminology.”

It feels like an academic word used in linguistics in the vein of “semiotics,” (but not dealing with signs, dealing with *terms*).  As an example, I imagine a biologist first creating the evolutionary tree, and splicing up each branch, like "mammal," and create the all the terms for the sub-species.

Kind of like creating jargon, but without the negative connotation and used more in a scholarly setting.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.   Thanks!

Comment: "Guess the word I'm trying to think of" questions are always tricky. The best word is probably *taxonomy/taxonomize* as already answered, but alternatives might be *ontology/ontologize*, or otherwise *classify* and its synonyms like organise, etc, or else words related to division like *bifurcate*.

Comment: Fair enough.  Nevertheless, taxonomy does feel like a good answer.  Hadn’t thought ontology, but that’s a good one as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably asking about *taxonomy,* which is well described by Wikipedia:

> Taxonomy is the practice and science of categorization or classification.
>
> A taxonomy (or taxonomical classification) is a scheme of classification, especially a hierarchical classification, in which things are organized into groups or types. Among other things, a taxonomy can be used to organize and index knowledge (stored as documents, articles, videos, etc.), such as in the form of a library classification system, or a search engine taxonomy, so that users can more easily find the information they are searching for. Many taxonomies are hierarchies (and thus, have an intrinsic tree structure), but not all are.
>
> Originally, taxonomy referred only to the categorisation of organisms or a particular categorisation of organisms. In a wider, more general sense, it may refer to a categorisation of things or concepts, as well as to the principles underlying such a categorisation. Taxonomy organizes taxonomic units known as "taxa" (singular "taxon").

OED gives a verb ***taxonomize.***

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, I think this is what I was looking for.  This feels right on.  Thank you greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You systematize terminology. This basically means that you create a useful map between the terminology of the domain and what you do with it or how you think about it. Medical terms are governed by SNOMED (Systematized NOmenclature for MEDicine). IUPAC's Chemical Nomenclature and Structure Representation Division governs chemical species names.

From [UPAIC](https://iupac.org/body/800/)

> Aims
> The Division is responsible for maintaining and developing standard systems for designating chemical structures, including both conventional nomenclature and computer-based systems.

Comment: Nomenclature alone is a good word here.  Thank you.